# How to map using Laravel BelongsTo Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a relationship between `your_electricity_yesterday_category` and `building` as `building_id` is present in `your_electricity_yesterday_category` table.

I am trying to get details out of the building table using the relationship.

I have this in my Electricity model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Electricity extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'your_electricity_yesterday_category';

    public function buildings()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Building::class, 'building_id');
    }
}
```

I have this in my Repository

```
public function getAllBuilding()
    {
        // $buildings = Building::where('module_electricity', 1)->orderBy('description')->get();

        $buildings = Electricity::with('buildings')->get();


        return $buildings;
    }
```

I have this in my controller

```
public function electBuilding()
    {
        $getBuilding = $this->electricityRepository->getAllBuilding();
        
        return response()->json($getBuilding);
    }
```

On the building table i have a column where `module_electricity` is either `0` or `1`

How can i use this relationship to return building where `module_electricity` is `1` in json?

Answer (score 1):

use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) query builder to filter parent Electricity details based on  condition

```
$buildings = Electricity::with(['buildings'=>function($query){
        $query->where('module_electricity',1);
      }])
      ->whereHas('buildings',function($query){
        $query->where('module_electricity',1);
      })->get();
```

Also you can write scope for where condition in buildings model like below

```
public function scopeModuleElectricity($query,$module){

   return $query->where('module_electricity',$module);
}
```

so your query will be

```
$buildings = Electricity::with(['buildings'=>function($query){
        $query->moduleElectricity(1);
      }])
      ->whereHas('buildings',function($query){
        $query->moduleElectricity(1);
      })->get();
```

Comment: That works so how can i access the building where module_electricity is 1 in vuejs.. currently i did this ```self.allBuilding = response.data``` how can i loop through building where module_electricity is 1?  @john lobo

Comment: @HenryOladeji .reverse releationship if you want buildings    $buildings=Building::moduleElectricity(1)->has('electricity')->get()

Comment: The reverse does not get the details from the electricity table...

Comment: @HenryOladeji if you need data then use with  $buildings=Building::with('electricity')->moduleElectricity(1)->has('electricity')->get()  .better if you provide smaple json data so i can modifiy query

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
public function getAllBuilding()
{
    return Electricity::query()
        ->with('buildings', fn ($query) => $query->where('module_electricity', 1))
        ->get()
        ->pluck('buildings')
        ->collapse();
}
```

Walking through this step by step so you can better understand what's happening:

1. Initiating a query (completely optional, just for better code formatting)
2. Eager loading buildings with a condition (module_electricity = 1)
3. Retrieving data from the database
4. Extracting buildings only
5. Flat-mapping results

This will return a single collection with buildings that met a condition.

Let me know if the result turned out to be exactly what you expected.

**P.S.** Note that the above solution might not work if you're using older versions of PHP. If the above returns syntax error:

replace:

```
fn ($query) => $query->where('module_electricity', 1)
```

with:

```
function ($query) {
    $query->where('module_electricity', 1)
}
```